# How to divide post into row with to post like wise in wordpress

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop, wordpress

I want to get wordpress post by selected category and display it like following

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
...
```

I don't have any idea how to loop this post. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

this is my wordpress code

```
<?php $args = array(
        'numberposts'     => 99999,
        'category_name'      => 'res-image-gallery');

                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();  ?>
                        //this block should like row with to post...
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="item"> </div>
                            <div class="item"> </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile;?>

                <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Please first check the $the_query and run this directly in phpmyadmin. Your code is fine.

Comment: @SumanSingh yes. what i want is loop this posts and divide it into rows with to posts. i want to know how it divide?

Comment: the $the_query->have_posts()  has all records and it iterate with  $the_query->the_post(); for each post items.

Comment: @SumanSingh i want to display it like row and add to post to that row and create new row and add next two post and create new row and add next two post like wise